# Using StringBuffer and Generics

Tags: java, generics, stringbuffer

I was trying to use StringBuffer and Generics, but the code won't compile:

[Gen.java]

```
class Gen<T> 
{
T ob;
//Constructor
Gen (T o)
{
 ob = o;
}

void showtype()
{
    System.out.println("Type of T is:"+ob.getClass().getName());
}

T getOb()
{
    return ob;
}

}
```

[GenDemo.java]

```
public class GenDemo
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Gen<StringBuffer> objStr;
    objStr = new Gen<StringBuffer> ("Hello"); //doesn't compile here.
    objStr.showtype();
    StringBuffer str = objStr.getOb();
}
}
```

I am a beginner. So, I apologize if this question is too basic for you. Can someone please help me? The code compiles well if I replace "StringBuffer" with "String"

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think it should compile? What surprises you about the error message? What do you think the type `StringBuffer` is? What's its relation with `String`?

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer. It was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago.

Comment: Can you post up there stack trace?

Comment: @KickButtowski if it doesn't compile, there won't be a stack trace (and it shouldn't compile)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey thank you. I learned something new, but what happened at compile time,  or runtime?

Comment: @KickButtowski this doesn't compile, so you will get a compiler error, which doesn't include a stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to initialise a `Gen<StringBuffer>` with a `String`. Change the initialisation to `objStr = new Gen<StringBuffer>(new StringBuffer("Hello"))` and everything should be fine.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks sisyphus. Also, I am new to this forum...So I clicked up arrow to give you a vote, but it shows "-1"--I am not sure whether this is equivalent to "Dislike". I sincerely apologize if it is. I am not familiar with stackoverflow. This was my first post.

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign between incompatible types in Java. e.g. you can't do this

```
StringBuilder sb = "Hello"; // the object String is not a StringBuilder
```

What you can do is pass a reference of one type to the constructor of another e.g.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello");
```

and you could do

```
Gen<String> str = new Gen<>("Hello");
```

or

```
Gen<StringBuilder> sb = new Gen<>(new StringBuilder("Hello"));
```

However, Java doesn't support implicit conversions of objects or references.